# Align Text Vertically in React Native

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

[image]I want to make my text like this in the picture. But my text is not centring vertically. How to achieve it?

What I have done so far is

```
<Fragment>
     <HeaderMain navigation={navigation}/>
     <View style={styles.subheader}>
       <Text style={styles.topText}>Заказы</Text>
     </View>
</Fragment>
```

**Styles**

```
container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingHorizontal: 8,
    paddingVertical: 7,
    backgroundColor: '#E5E5E5',
},
subheader:{
    height: 55,
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
    flexDirection: 'column',
},
topText:{
    fontWeight: "bold",
    fontSize: 17,
    lineHeight:21,
    fontFamily: MONREGULAR,
    marginLeft: 16,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
},
```

Comment: Your subheader view doesn't have a closing tag.

Comment: I unintentionally forgot to add, thank you for mentioning it

Comment: But the problem is on queue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `justifyContent`, `alignItems` in `Text`. You should use it in `View`. Also give lineHeight same values as your fontSize. Like this;

```
subheader:{
    height: 55,
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'center',
},

topText:{
    fontWeight: "bold",
    fontSize: 17,
    lineHeight: 21,
    fontFamily: MONREGULAR,
    marginLeft: 16,
},
```

Comment: you centered but not like this picture

Comment: Remove `justifyContent: center`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
`subheader` should be of `display:flex` and `flex-direction:column`
`topText` should have `justify-content:space-around`

```
subheader:{
    height: 55,
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    display: flex;
}

topText:{
    fontWeight: "bold",
    fontSize: 17,
    lineHeight:21,
    fontFamily: MONREGULAR,
    marginLeft: 16,
    justifyContent: 'space-around'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

alignItems and justifyContent are used to adjust components within a view. If what you want is to center the content within a text you should use: textAlign, in your case I think you should use:

```
textAlign: "center"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
subheader:{
  height: 55,
  backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
  flexDirection: 'column',
  justifyContent: 'center',
  alignItems: 'center',
},

topText:{
    fontWeight: "bold",
    fontSize: 17,
    lineHeight: 21,
    fontFamily: MONREGULAR,
    marginLeft: 16,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
},
```